# Bug in setting background image for html screen

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Below `Media screen 929px` I am getting a scroll bar and white screen occurs .
The images is attached here

[image].

If I am not giving `overflow:auto or hidden` ,my background is not visible too. Need assistance.

```
@media  screen and (min-width: 831px) and (max-width: 929px)  {

 .content1 {
    width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    background-image: url('images/signin bg.png');
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: auto;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

html :

```
<div class="content1" ng-controller="LoginController as ctrl">
   <form name="form" role="form" class="col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-3" ng-submit="vm.login()"> 
   <input type="email" placeholder="EMAIL/ USERNAME" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username" required />
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="PASSWORD" ng-model="vm.password" required />
        <button class="btn1 col-sm-7" type="submit">SUBMIT
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: so where do the background should be? put some html maybe?

Comment: uhm... get rid of the space in the file-name

Comment: Maybe a fiddle or a snippet ?

Comment: Given html code. please look